Handbrake causes brakes to stick on accord v6 2008
I bought an Honda accord v6 2008 a few months ago and the owner told me the handbrake didn’t work. He said that if I were to engage the handbrake, the brakes would stick. I didn’t think much of it and thought I would try to fix it myself during the summer but now here I am and I’m not sure what I’m supposed to do? Is it because the calipers are done? Is it because the pads are done? What’s the problem? I’ve never engaged the handbrake because I don’t want the brakes to stick so I don’t know if it’s even true. Thank you for your help in advance! *Might also be useful to know that the guy cleaned the brakes before selling it to me so the problem might already be fixed without me knowing?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Presumably you were misinformed. The handbrake works, but can't be released. That might be a fault with the cable or ratchet, etc., not the brakes themselves.

I am in a snow belt where salt is used on the roads. When I worked in a shop or if I worked on someone else's car with cabled parking brakes I would never apply parking brakes because it would be very possible to have them seize and I'd end up with a unhappy customer needing unexpected repairs. The best preventative solution is to use the brakes often as mentioned. The cables are fairly easy to diagnose. If you can wait until the next brake service, do not use them in the meantime and have your mechanic inspect them and repair as necessary. If you park on hilly roads and find it necessary for safety reasons, they can be diagnosed and fixed right away. Just cleaning the parts in the drum brake area will not help with bad cables, which is the most likely cause.

It's not out of the question that the handbrake cable has become fouled or corroded. Such a circumstance has happened to me but in a much older vehicle. If one does not customarily use the handbrake, any exposed portions of the cable can deteriorate.
What happens next is that the handbrake will have an increased diameter, which upon actuation, gets jammed in the housing and will not release, or will only partially release, just to jam up the next time.
According to the internet, your vehicle has rear drum brakes. This means that the cable runs to a lever inside the drum, which also presents a small section of unprotected cable, which can corrode.
It's possible to remove the drum and force the lever to release the cable, but the wiser route is to remove both cables and replace them. Consider to use the brake periodically. A good habit is to actuate the handbrake whenever parked, but also to release when ready to drive. Use enough force to set the brake, while pressing firmly on the brake pedal and you will have a strong enough braking applied to prevent accidental drive-away with the handbrake engaged.
If you can apply the handbrake and then engage the vehicle for driving and it moves, you didn't use enough force while setting it.
